# How to write text onto excel using csv file in python

Tags: python, string, excel, csv, text

I am trying to write some text onto csv file. When I open it each letter is taking a cell. But I want each string to be in a cell. How do I do it. I am using python 2.7.10

Here is the simple code:

```
with open("output.csv",'wb') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
   writer.writerows('Apples:10 Mangoes:15 bananas:20')
```

I want output to be like this(total 6 cells)

```
Apples    10     Mangoes    15    Bananas    20
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a couple changes. First, instead of `writerows`, utilize [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow). Second, you need to pass a list of elements instead of a string:

```
writer.writerow(['Apples','10','Mangoes','15','bananas','20'])
```

This will create a document that looks like this:

[image: Excel output]

Answer (score 2):

First, you should properly format your string:

```
Apples:10 Mangoes:15 bananas:20
```

Should be:

```
Apples,10,Mangoes,15,bananas,20
```

Then you can write a CSV which is easily imported into excel.

Second, if your final destination is writing excel files you should take a look at [Pandas to export your data to excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), it has the convenient method:

```
pandas.DataFrame.to_excel
```

If your data is simpler, you can work directly with [xlswriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply split your long string into every row you want :

```
    my_str = 'Apples:10 Mangoes:15 bananas:20'
    writer.writerow( my_str.replace(':',' ').split() )
```

which will put spaces everywhere you want your string to split and then split it.

Comment: I need to write several rows of the same data. I see only one row which is being written onto file though I am looping over it. Please suggest.